# Restler 3 HTTPS issue?

Tags: php, api, rest, https, restler

So, I've just moved my project to a new server, and on this server i can access

```
http://url/api/auth/login
```

but I cannot access

```
https://url/api/auth/login
```

(I get a blank page :(

So, it's weird because I can get to

```
https://url/api
```

which is where index.php is and I just get "message":"not found" which is fine.  But it shows that at the root level, Restler is working.

But I can't go any deeper than that.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, it was an issue with my httpd.conf file 
I had

All is good now.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all #this WAS None.  Had to change it to all
```